# elk security. stash to beat, beat to stash

Tags: security, elasticsearch, debian, logstash, filebeat

We are moving our logging from an external partner to ourselves in-house. The ELK is pretty much setup and working. 
BUT somehow securing the beat to stash connection is not working.
X-pack is installed. Filebeat is in also in use.

How are you guys securing your own ELK?
Iam trying stuff from [HERE](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html), [HERE](http://www.gilesorr.com/blog/elkbeats-beats-secure.html) and pretty much any thing else that comes up at ze old google.

EDIT: Everything is up and running. So next step would be securing the filebeat to logstash connection... Which is simply NOT working with the in x-pack included certificate-creation-tool-thingy.
From LogstashLog:

```
"[ERROR][logstash.inputs.beats    ] Looks like you either have an invalid key or your private key was not in PKCS8 format. {:exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: bla/bla/bla.key"
```

Already had it in the PKCS8 format, but it gave the same error..

From FilebeatLog:

```
"ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): read tcp xxx.xxx.x.xxx:49914->yyy.yyy.y.yyy:5043: i/o timeout"
```

Thanks in Advance

EDIT2: I've redone this now thousand times. Still the same Errors.
If i change something on the .key files, like the permissions, with:

```
"chmod 644 ca.key"
```

.. i get an different error:

```
"[INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt, from: /xxx.xxx.x.xxx:"
```

...which translates to connection refused by peer..

Has someone an idea?
EDIT3:

.. if i test the connection with:

```
"openssl s_client -connect yyy.yyy.y.yyy:aaaa"
```

it works. i can connect. BUT:

```
"verify error:num=18:self signed certificate"
```

And now the the FilebeatLog tells me:

```
"x509: cannot validate certificate for yyy.yyy.y.yyy because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"
```

.. which is total BS. i followed those to guides: [HERE][3] and this: [HERE][4]. (which i cant post 'cause of reputation limit.)

NEXT EDIT:
After my third cert recreation. It works! WUHUU. BUT, AGAIN: an error. Yes, nothing really bad, but i want to understand this.

```
"Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)"
```

Why?

NEXT EDIT2: after a restart it came to dis:

```
"depth=0 CN = yyyy
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = yyyy
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
140581134010112:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1399:SSL alert number 40"
```

still: why?

---

SO, that question is too complex i think for most people.

my final question would be:

Logstash-Log showing "OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE"
Filebeat-Log showing "ERR Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxxx->yyy.yyy.y.yyy:yyyy: write: connection reset by peer
INFO Error publishing events (retrying): write tcp xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxxx->yyy.yyy.y.yyy:yyyy: write: connection reset by peer"

..even after renewing all certs. if i connect with openssl it works, if i use curl not. 
any idea on why and how?

Thanks

Comment: You should add more details if you want an answer, like what's not working, error messages, relevant logs, configuration used...

Comment: *follow up: 
[3]: https://serverfault.com/a/611121
  [4]: http://www.itrig.de/index.php?/archives/2170-Selbstsignierte-Zertifikate-mit-Subject-Alternative-Names-SANs-fuer-Apache,-Nginx-oder-Tomcat-erstellen.html

Answer (score 0):

After following multiple articles on how to set this up, I encountered something not mentioned in any of them. (maybe its new addition?)

In Logstash 7.2.0, when `ssl_certificate_authorities => ["/etc/logstash/pki/ca.crt"]` is configured - this force the server to validate the client certificate (what called Mutual TLS).

I had to remove it from the logstash configuration, and the `OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE` error resolved.

The logstash input config look like this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => ".../server.crt"
    ssl_key => ".../server.key"
    ssl_verify_mode => "none"
  }
}
```